# Create a canonical Q&A for installing a blank OS without MAS with a link to a hosted copy of the installers

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

I have been seeing a lot of questions like: "I want to install El Capitan, but I never got it from the App Store. How can I do this?"

The best option for this is "Get a friend with the installer." I have installers going back to Mavericks. Would it be useful and legal for me to create a Google Drive account where I could post these installers? The idea would be that I could create a canonical question/answer so that each time a question like this comes up, we can mark it as a duplicate of the question with a link to all of the installers.

Comment: How would anyoine know they did not have trojans or viruses added?

Comment: @Mark Is there not a way to verify the apps? Either because they are signed by Apple or by having an antivirus scan them while they are in Google Drive? I know that they do not contain viruses (being that I own them and have used them regularly), but I want to be able to prove it to anyone who wants to download them.

Comment: Alternatively, I could put a disclaimer on the question, noting that anyone should run an antivirus scan on the file before opening it.

Comment: Which anti virus scan - and are any 100% OK - basic rulew is only download from the author and even then check

Comment: @Mark I understand the security concerns. I also understand that people have a hard time getting their hands on these installers. I'm trying to provide easy access to these installers without sacrificing security. Can you think of any good ways to do this? Also, is the fact that the app is signed by Apple (and its checksum returns ok) an ok indicator that it hasn't been tampered with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting an illegal copy off a random person is **not** the best way. One should use the official links from Apple to obtain a copy, or there are alternative methods such as Internet Recovery.

Any such questions can be marked as duplicate of the existing questions with viable questions.